# Chrome Extension, messaging: getting port status

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get a port's status in an application (not a content script). When I do :

`this.port = chrome.runtime.connect("okcbadfdlhldjgkbafhnkcpofabckgde");`

I get a valid `port` object but I can't find anyway to determine if the port can be used at all (I don't even get a `disconnect` event if the extension can't be reached).

The only way I figured out to have the connectivity state is to actually trap an exception when performing a `this.port.postMessage`.

Is there a better way ?

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect

**Update**

- Running Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) on Linux Ubuntu
- No cross-extension messaging, just application to/from extension
- Extension [source code](https://github.com/jldupont/chrome.hue) but note I have since moved on to implement another strategy for the extension because of the issue raised in this question.

Comment: If I add `chrome.runtime.connect("okcbadfdlhldjgkbafhnkcpofabckgde").onDisconnect.addListener(function(e){console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError)});` seems to work for me (no receiver -> `Object {message: "Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist."}`) in Chrome 48.0.2564.82). What's your setup, and have you already tried Chrome Beta (49)? Chrome's implementation of extension message ports has received an overhaul in Chrome 49, which has addressed some issues with extension message ports. See https://codereview.chromium.org/1413543005/, at "- Extension messaging".

Comment: Are you trying to perform cross-extension messaging?

Comment: @GLES @RobW I have included an `update` section to answer your questions. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Is it possible to view the source code for the application, like it is for the extension?

Comment: @GLES added pointer to source code

Comment: @GLES FYI, I couldn't figure out a better so I changed strategy.

Answer (score 2):

Your extension uses a `background-script` that provides listener function for the `chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal` event. This event is used to listen for incoming messages, send from external webpage-scripts (or other extensions) by calling the `chrome.runtime.sendMessage` method.

Since your extension does not provide a listener function for the `chrome.runtime.onConnectExternal` event, `chrome.runtime.connect` cannot work for your extension.

As far as knowing the connection status is concerned, in this case a simple `try-catch` block would do enough to know whether the extension supports `port` or not. If it does, you need to view the `manifest` corresponding to this extension - to see if a particular host is allowed to send messages or not.

I was able to send message to your extension (see the enclosed figure) by adding the following lines of code in the background-script. In addition to this, I also added the `matches` string for the host - `www.example.org` in the manifest.

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
    function(request, _sender, sendResponse) {
        console.log(request);
        ...
    }
);
```

[image: image-1]

Comment: Thanks for your time but this does not any additional information to what I have already provided.

Comment: Your extension **does not** contain the listener function for the `onConnectExternal` event, how are you even able to create the `port` object?